# как скачать видео adobe flash по ссылке

Tags: bash, cmd, vlc

Нужно ли эмулировать веб браузер или  можно найти что-то готовое ?

Comment: `curl -X GET -O <filename> <URL>`

Comment: так нельзя скачать флеш http://paste.debian.net/1007803/

Comment: ок. Но можно сделать иначе. В selenium(вроде есть порт на bash) открыть браузер и начать проигрывание. В это время вытащить видео из кеша.

Comment: Попробуй `youtube-dl`. Есть вероятность, что прожуёт.

Comment: youtube-dl неверный формат url

Comment: `selenium` это слишком непросто.

Comment: @Yurjj, есть ещё вариант, который мне больше всего нравится, не надо пользоваться уродскими технологиями (flash).